# Large POCO- Control JSON generation at runtime

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a large C#/.Net POCO class that I will have to serialize to JSON using a UmbracoAPIController, right now it all works fine but the JSON is pretty big.

I have two scenarios where the POCO will be serialized to JSON, in scenario 1 the user will only need see a fraction of the data from the JSON, and in the second scenario the user need to see allmost the full JSON.

I use the [JsonIgnoreAttribute] to control whether a given property will be serialized to JSON or not, it also works fine.

I have this code in an ancestor class A:

```
//[JsonIgnoreAttribute]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "insured")]
public virtual UIInsuredModel[] Insured { get; set; }
```

Then I have a descendant class B that inherits from A

```
[JsonIgnoreAttribute]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "insured")]
public override UIInsuredModel[] Insured { get; set; }
```

Is there a nice way of declaring/adding the [JsonIgnoreAttribute] at runtime for a given property in the POCO ?, instead of using the current "solution" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an attribute to a compiled type in runtime.

You may consider using reflection but that's only relevant to static metadata that can't be changed and applied to the type in runtime.